# IBM Blockchain Platform VS Code GOPATH Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibp-vscode-extension

I am getting this error when i am packaging my smart contract project in VS code IBM extendion

The Go smart contract is not a subdirectory of the path specified by the environment variable GOPATH. Please correct the environment variable GOPATH.

This is the image of my error and my path variables

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqbq1.jpg

Comment: Can you please tell absolute path of your chaincode ?

Answer (score 4):

First you should confirm that vscode is picking up your GOPATH. If you open the terminal view in vscode and type

```
echo $GOPATH
```

to confirm the gopath matches. Then you need to open VSCode to the location of your Go chaincode which must be in the `src` directory in your go workspace pointed to by your go path. For example here is my go chaincode project called testcc and the actual chaincode source is in `mycc`

```
└── testcc
    ├── bin
    ├── pkg
    │   └── linux_amd64
    └── src
        ├── github.com
        ├── golang.org
        └── mycc
```

located at `~/mycode`. Therefore I would have a GOPATH of `~/mycode/testcc` and I would open vscode up at the mycc directory. For example I would launch vscode as follows

```
$ GOPATH=~/mycode/testcc code ~/mycode/testcc/src/mycc
```